# problem when trying to use terraform remote mirrors on artifactory

Tags: terraform

I am trying to work together with some colleagues on setting up a static mirror on artifactory to avoid doing so many remote pulls from the remote repository.
I read this articles and I thought I was all set but I'm still failing and I wanted to know if I could get some hints.

https://www.terraform.io/internals/provider-network-mirror-protocol
https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#network_mirror

So I have defined the mirror and I can see some plugins in it
[image]

And then I configured it in my configs:

```
provider_installation {
    network_mirror {
        url = "https://registry.sits.abc.net/virtual-generic-terraform-cp/"
    }
}
```

(UPDATE first issue was the missing trialing /)

However when I do my terraform init I am getting problems with accessing the providers.

```
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
â•·
â”‚ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
â”‚
â”‚ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
â”‚ hashicorp/aws: host registry.sits.abc.net rejected the given
â”‚ authentication credentials
â•µ

â•·
â”‚ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
â”‚
â”‚ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
â”‚ hashicorp/random: failed to query provider mirror
â”‚ https://registry.sits.abc.net/virtual-generic-terraform-cp/ for
â”‚ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random: invalid response content from
â”‚ mirror server: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
â•µ
```

I have the provide in my code defined as I normally do it.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

By looking at the log I wonder if I need to define the provider in a different way now that I'm trying to use a mirror?

Any tips are welcomed it's very likely I'm doing something wrong on my side since I recently started exploring terraform

Comment: If I am reading the documentation right, you need to have a trailing slash at the end of the `url`, i.e. `url = "https://registry.sits.abc.net/virtual-generic-terraform-cp/"`. More info here: https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#:~:text=the%20https%3A%20scheme%20and%20end%20with%20a%20trailing%20slash.

Comment: thanks for the feedback that was for sure part of the problem but now I edited the question because I'm getting a different error. 
"Error: Failed to query available provider packages"

Comment: I would think there is something wrong with the registry implementation. Can you try with this and see if you get anything: https://www.terraform.io/internals/provider-network-mirror-protocol#provider-mirror-as-a-static-website?

Comment: Or alternatively, you can take a look here: https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20if,com/examplecorp/ourcloud.